# How to have name of int from string

Tags: c#

I have 3 strings that have names of ints in them. I don't know how to use the ints with their names from strings. I mean, that int player1 has value 10. I store the name of that int - player1 in string. And I want to use the variable player1 somewhere, but instead of typing player1 I type the name of the string - it is not to make my jod easier, but I need it in a algorithm, so I can swith the order of the ints in that algorithm

```
            a = "player3";
            b = "player1";
            c = "player2";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                //the name of int from string a//[i] = cardStack[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                //the name of int from string b//[i] = cardStack[i + 5];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                //the name of int from string c//[i] = cardStack[i + 10];
            }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, please?

Comment: The most similar function I can think of is [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how extract an `int` with value `1` from the string `"player1"`?

Comment: opinion: I don't think the linked dup is a good reference for this question; this seems much more like a "use a list/array and indexer" scenario than a "use a field by name" scenario; it also isn't clear to me that the code in the question is even *talking about* fields

Comment: @Marc: dictionary would be a more idiomatic way to approach this, and that's one of the answers on the duplicate. Other alternatives, such as creating a user-defined type that puts the player name _and_ the `cardStack` array in the same object, and then accesses those by index would also be viable. I'm sure there are questions that provide that sort of solution, if you want to add that to the duplicates list. The odds that this question is _not_ a duplicate are slim to none.

Comment: @PeterDuniho oh, I'm not saying it isn't a duplicate - I'm just saying that *that linked one* is possibly not the most useful; if I find a better one, I'll add it

Comment: I mean, that int player1 has value 10. I store the name of that int - player1 in string. And I want to use the variable player1 somewhere, but instead of typing player1 I type the name of the string - it is not to make my jod easier, but I need it in a algorithm, so I can swith the order of the ints in that algorithm.